# Elliptic curves with supersingular reduction have irreducible mod $p$ representations?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q_p$ and suppose that $E$ has good reduction at a prime $p$. I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107175/does-the-p-torsion-of-an-elliptic-curve-with-good-reduction-over-a-local-field) that if $E$ has ordinary (resp. supersingular) reduction at $p$ then the mod $p$ representation of $E$ is reducible (resp. irreducible). Why is this true?  If the reduction at $p$ is ordinary, I think reducibility follows essentially because the reduction map $E[p]\rightarrow \tilde E[p]$ is $G_{\mathbb Q_p}$-equivariant, so its kernel is a $G_{\mathbb Q_p}$-stable copy of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ in $E[p]$. But in the supersingular case, the reduction map is just zero, so it doesn't seem to be of any help... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: $K=Q_p(E[p])$ for $E$ good supersingular reduction and $E[p]$ a reducible $G_{Q_p}$. With the formal group law $E_{formal}(\pi_K O_K)\cong \ker(E(K)\to \tilde{E})$ we can say a good amount of things. If we can show the valuation is the same for all point of $E[p]-O$ then we get a contradiction.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure I understand your comment. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see this is that, as a consequence of  the theory of formal groups,  the image of inertia via the mod-$p$ representation is a (full) non-split Cartan subgroup. Since the non-split Cartan has no fixed non-trivial submodules of order $p$, the representation itself must be irreducible. All of this is nicely shown in a well-known paper of Serre (where he proves the so-called "open image theorem"), and you can see a summary of what you need in [Section 3 of this article](https://production.wordpress.uconn.edu/alozano/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/07/lozano-robledo_torsion_bounds_v12.pdf), and in particular in Theorem 3.1.

Comment: Why is it a non-split Cartan subgroup ?

Comment: @reuns because the reduction is good supersingular, the formal group is of height $2$, and the $p$-torsion has a $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$-vector space structure of dimension $1$. Thus, the automorphism group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^\ast$ which when embedded in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a non-split Cartan.

Comment: With $L= \overline{Q_p}$ and $F=E_{formal}(\mathfrak{m}_L)$ then $F=\ker(E\to \tilde{E}),F_{torsion} = E[p^\infty]= Z[p^{-1}]^2/Z^2$ (because for $p\nmid n$, $[n]$ is separable on the reduction so its roots lift to $L$) and $Aut(F_{torsion}) = GL_2(Z_p)$. How does it relate to the $Gal(L/Q_p)$-module $E[p]$ ? Are you saying elements of $Aut(F_{torsion})$ are endomorphism defined over some field ?

Comment: You have to look at how inertia acts to see the non-split Cartan appear. The image of all of the absolute Galois group can be larger.

Comment: Please make it clear the few non-trivial facts you are assuming.. I don't understand what you mean with "automorphism" and how you know the action of the inertia on $E[p]$.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the details are explained in Serre's paper, Section 1: https://www.wstein.org/sage_summer/bsd_comp/Serre-properties_galoisiennes_des_points_dordre_fini_des_courbes_elliptiques.pdf